# How to toggle a class of an input element when a value is inserted on that element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a javascript handler on an input html element. The input html elements may be many.. The point is whenever I insert a value on the input html element I would like to add a class on that element in order to change the background-color of the input that has a value. Right now I am doing: **$('this.seat_box').toggleClass('selected');******** but this will affect all the elements that has the class. Is there a way to pass an argument on the handler function in the input element refering somehow to this? I have tried to pass the arguments or argument like:
onchange="bc.seatBoxHandleEvent('input', this) and none of these worked...

Any help appreciated.!

The Html code:

```
<div class="bus-builder-seat-box-container" id="dynamic-bus-builder-1">
  <input id="posA100" type="text" class="seat_box" onchange="bc.seatBoxHandleEvent()">
  <input id="posA101" type="text" class="seat_box" onchange="bc.seatBoxHandleEvent()">
</div>
```

I have the following code for javascript validation:

```
bc.seatBoxHandleEvent = function () {
  bc.checkInput();
  var seatNumberFirstFloor = $('#dynamic-bus-builder-1');
  if (seatNumberFirstFloor && seatNumberFirstFloor.valueOf()) {
    var leftStreaming = (event.target.id);
    var rightStreaming = 'posB1' + leftStreaming.substring(5, 7);
    document.getElementById(rightStreaming).innerHTML = event.target.value;
  }
}

bc.checkInput = function () {
  var targetValue = event.target.value;
  var id = event.target.id;
  var classOfInput = event.target.classList;
  if (targetValue !== 8 && targetValue !== 0 && (targetValue < 48 || targetValue > 57)) {
    console.log('valid number');
    console.log(classOfInput);
    **$('this.seat_box').toggleClass('selected');********
  }
  else {
    console.log('invalid character');
  }
}
```

Comment: `$('this.seat_box')` doesn't make sense for any purpose, because `this` is a keyword, it shouldn't be in quotes. Try `$(this).toggleClass('selected')`.

Comment: thank you but it wont work.. I tried it now and I have tried it before....

Comment: Oh, sorry, I just realised all of your functions are methods of an object called `bc`, and the way you're calling them `this` would be `bc`. In that case you'd need to pass the `event` object through as an argument and use `event.target` to get a reference to the element that the event happened to. Given you're using jQuery, is there some reason why you're not binding event handlers with jQuery?

Comment: Do you mean to pass the argument like that: onchange="bc.seatBoxHandleEvent('event.target')" and then with jQuery: $(bc).toggleClass('selected'); there isn't any reason that I implemented it with js...

Comment: You'd need to also pass the `event` through from within -`seatBoxHandleEvent()` to `checkInput()`, then `$(event.target).toggleClass()`. And sorry, I only just noticed you're already using `event` in your function as if it is a global variable - that won't work in all browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the element to the function from HTML.

```js
bc = [];
bc.seatBoxHandleEvent = function (el) {
 bc.checkInput(el);

 var seatNumberFirstFloor = $('#dynamic-bus-builder-1');

 if (seatNumberFirstFloor && seatNumberFirstFloor.valueOf()) {

    var leftStreaming = (event.target.id);
    var rightStreaming = 'posB1' + leftStreaming.substring(5, 7);

 }
}

bc.checkInput = function (el) {
 var targetValue = event.target.value;
 var id = event.target.id;
 var classOfInput = event.target.classList;

 if (targetValue !== 8 && targetValue !== 0 && (targetValue < 48 || targetValue > 57)) {


    console.log('valid number');
    console.log(classOfInput);
    $(el).toggleClass('selected');


 }
 else {
    console.log('invalid character');
 }
}
```

```css
div.class1 {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #FFCC00;
}

.selected {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bus-builder-seat-box-container" id="dynamic-bus-builder-1">
 <input id="posA100" type="text" class="seat_box" onchange="bc.seatBoxHandleEvent(this)">
 <input id="posA101" type="text" class="seat_box" onchange="bc.seatBoxHandleEvent(this)">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did just rewrote bc to an object instead, the syntax is apart from that the same. But this one works. Remember that the onchange event is only trigger on blur. So if you want the event to trigger when entering a value then use onkeypress event instead.

JS

```
var BC = function () {
  this.seatBoxHandleEvent = function () {

    var checkInput = function () {

      var targetValue = event.target.value;
      var id = '#' + event.target.id;

      if (targetValue !== 8 && targetValue !== 0 && (targetValue < 48 || targetValue > 57)) {
        console.log('valid number');
        console.log(event.target.classList); // [seat-box] set on the event.target
        $(id).toggleClass('selected');
        console.log(event.target.classList); // [seat-box, selected] set on the event.target
      }
      else {
        console.log('invalid character');
      }
    };

    checkInput();
  };
};

this.bc = new BC();
```

HTML

```
<div class="bus-builder-seat-box-container" id="dynamic-bus-builder-1">
  <input id="posA100" type="text" class="seat_box" onchange="bc.seatBoxHandleEvent()">
  <input id="posA101" type="text" class="seat_box" onchange="bc.seatBoxHandleEvent()">
</div>
```